# Create a Horizontal dotted line in android layout

Tags: android

in my layout I am trying to draw a DOTTED LINE.for drawing a horizontal line i am defining a view in my layout file.

```
     <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="@drawable/customdots" />
```

and customdots.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item
    android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:width="4dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/dotted" />

 </layer-list>
```

dotted.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line" >

  <size
    android:height="4dp"
    android:width="1024dp"/>
  <stroke
   android:width="4dp" 
   android:dashWidth="4dp"
   android:color="@android:color/black"
   android:dashGap="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

But i don't get any line using this code. please help me out.

When i use customdots.xml in the listView Divider as

```
 android:divider="@drawable/customdots"
```

it shows a good dotted line

Comment: android:left="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:width="4dp"

does it make sense?

Comment: @pskink what should it be in your opinion.

Answer (score 52):

I was pulling my hair on this issue too until I figured out there is a bug in the latest versions of Android when rendering lines like this.

This bug can be circumvented by adding **android:layerType="software"** to the view which is using the dotted line as a background.

**Example:**

dotted.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line">

<stroke
    android:dashGap="3dp"
    android:dashWidth="8dp"
    android:height="2px"
    android:color="#FFFFFF" />

</shape>
```

layout.xml:

```
    <View
        android:id="@+id/vDottedLine"
        android:background="@drawable/dotted"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2px"
        android:layerType="software" />
```

Comment: ndroid:layerType="software" is the key

Comment: it seemed not to work on Android 5.0, nothing was showed

Comment: This code works only if `stroke` has a `width` attribute instead of `height`. `layerType` is also required.

Comment: @kasimir Why are you using `px` instead of `dp`?

Comment: I was using `px` it looked best for my screen on my test devices. Otherwise no specific reason, `dp` should work as well.

Comment: But, why layerType?

Comment: `android:layerType="software"` just means that Android should render this View using the software layer and not the normally faster layer which tries to use the device's graphics hardware via the driver. The time I wrote this tip there was a bug in the hardware layer when rendering dotted lines. Don't know if this is still the case (4 years later).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code . it may help you.
Create a dotted.xml in drawable folder like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" >
       <stroke
       android:color="#A52A2A"
       android:dashWidth="10px"
       android:dashGap="10px" />

</shape>
```

then use this xml in your layout with image view like this....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is above line of code " />
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dottede" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="this is below code " />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i still don't get a visible line. it shows a image view with no image. Same thing with my above code.

Comment: same here. Perhaps this worked on an older version of Android?

Comment: @SAURABH Why are you using ImageView for divider instead of View?