# Dotted line in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I am working on android application in which I want to use dotted line xml as a divider in my layout. For this I have used different drawables but instead to make a dashed dotted line, it is making a line. My image is given below

[image]

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103713/how-do-i-make-a-dotted-dashed-line-in-android) answer.It may help in your problem.

Comment: This solved my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441081/create-a-horizontal-dotted-line-in-android-layout

Comment: Thanks for the dup link, will vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

in your ListView put

```html
android:divider="@drawable/dash"
```

And in drawable folder create dash.xml and put following code

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:color="#fdfdfd"
        android:width="1dp"
        android:dashGap="3dp"
        android:dashWidth="1dp"
        />
    <size
        android:height="3dp"
        />
</shape>
```

You can also change the color of dot